# Save OpenGL screen pixels to PNG using libpng

Tags: c++, c, opengl, image-manipulation, libpng

I've been using SOIL to save images as BMP, but it turns out that SOIL (or stbi to be more specific) saves ~5MB images (which is about 1366x768 resolution image or more) which is quite insane.

Original BMP saving code (**NOTE** Everything is done in the render function):

```
uint8_t *pixels = new uint8_t[w * h * 3];
// copy pixels from screen
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTex);
glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, w, h);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid *)pixels);

// invert pixels (stolen from SOILs source code)
for (int j = 0; j * 2 < h; ++j) {
    int x = j * w * 3;
    int y = (h - 1 - j) * w * 3;
    for (int i = w * 3; i > 0; --i) {
        uint8_t tmp = pixels[x];
        pixels[x] = pixels[y];
        pixels[y] = tmp;
        ++x;
        ++y;
    }
}

// save the image
int err = SOIL_save_image(fileName, SOIL_SAVE_TYPE_BMP, w, h, 3, pixels);
if (err)
   printf("Done\n");
else
   printf("Failed\n");
```

Code for saving PNG:

```
bool save_png_libpng(const char *filename, uint8_t *pixels, int w, int h)
{
    png_structp png = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!png)
        return false;

    png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
    if (!info) {
        png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);
        return false;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);
        return false;
    }

    png_init_io(png, fp);
    png_set_IHDR(png, info, w, h, 8 /* depth */, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
        PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);
    png_colorp palette = (png_colorp)png_malloc(png, PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH * sizeof(png_color));
    if (!palette) {
        fclose(fp);
        png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);
        return false;
    }
    png_set_PLTE(png, info, palette, PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH);
    png_write_info(png, info);
    png_set_packing(png);

    png_bytepp rows = (png_bytepp)png_malloc(png, h * sizeof(png_bytep));
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
        rows[i] = (png_bytep)(pixels + (h - i) * w * 3);

    png_write_image(png, rows);
    png_write_end(png, info);
    png_free(png, palette);
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);

    fclose(fp);
    delete[] rows;
    return true;
}
```

**NOTE**:  I have not changed any of the original code, just replaced `SOIL_save_image` with `save_png`.

The code fails in the following line:

`png_write_image(png, rows)`

in PNG's source code, this function fails at the highlighted line:

```
void PNGAPI
png_write_image(png_structrp png_ptr, png_bytepp image)
{
   png_uint_32 i; /* row index */
   int pass, num_pass; /* pass variables */
   png_bytepp rp; /* points to current row */

   if (png_ptr == NULL)
      return;

   png_debug(1, "in png_write_image");

#ifdef PNG_WRITE_INTERLACING_SUPPORTED
   /* Initialize interlace handling.  If image is not interlaced,
    * this will set pass to 1
    */
   num_pass = png_set_interlace_handling(png_ptr);
#else
   num_pass = 1;
#endif
   /* Loop through passes */
   for (pass = 0; pass < num_pass; pass++)
   {
      /* Loop through image */
      for (i = 0, rp = image; i < png_ptr->height; i++, rp++)
      {
         png_write_row(png_ptr, *rp); // HERE
      }
   }
}
```

`png_write_row` then fails here:  (The code for png_write_row is quite long to post here, so if you're curious about what happens before this line, you can check out pngwrite.c in png's source code.  )

```
   /* Copy user's row into buffer, leaving room for filter byte. */
   memcpy(png_ptr->row_buf + 1, row, row_info.rowbytes);
```

**P.S:** I was using exactly the same code on MinGW and it was working 100% fine, when I switched to MSVC it started failing.  I'm not sure if GCC does something magically here or it's my code's fault, so I would like to know for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following line:

`rows[i] = (png_bytep)(pixels + (h - i) * w * 3);`

is unforunately going past the block of memory (`pixels`), so the following edit fixes it:

`rows[i] = (png_bytep)(pixels + (h - i - 1) * w * 3);`

Quite trivial but whatever.