# Writing PNG file from pixel data using libpng

Tags: c++, opengl, libpng

I am trying to write PNG file (saving an image in png format) from pixel data read by glReadPixels in openGL using following piece of code (copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853224/save-opengl-screen-pixels-to-png-using-libpng/22573255?noredirect=1#comment34362291_22573255)):

```
bool writePNGFileFromBuffer(const char *filename, unsigned char *pixels, int w, int h)
{
    png_structp png = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL,     NULL);//8
    if (!png)
        return false;

png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);//7
if (!info) {
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);//
    return false;
}

FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
if (!fp) {
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);//
    return false;
}
png_init_io(png, fp);//9
png_set_IHDR(png, info, w, h, 8 /* depth */, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
    PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);//10
png_colorp palette = (png_colorp)png_malloc(png, PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH * sizeof(png_color));//4
if (!palette) {
    fclose(fp);
    png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);//
    return false;
}
png_set_PLTE(png, info, palette, PNG_MAX_PALETTE_LENGTH);//12
png_write_info(png, info);//1
png_set_packing(png);//5

png_bytepp rows = (png_bytepp)png_malloc(png, h * sizeof(png_bytep));//
for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
    rows[i] = (png_bytep)(pixels + (h - i) * w * 3);

png_write_image(png, rows);//2
png_write_end(png, info);//6
png_free(png, palette);//11
png_destroy_write_struct(&png, &info);//3

fclose(fp);
delete[] rows;
return true;
}
```

I linked the libpng and zlib libraries in the additional dependencies. But when I compile the code it gives following error:

Error   77  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol png_write_info

It gives this error at about 12 instances marked in the code snippet above. I am clear that it is not able to find the definitions of the functions but I do not know why?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit: I looked into the header file "png.h" and it contains declarations for all the functions. Functions are defined in "pngwrite.c" and I think it should take it from the linked library.

Edit2: After hitting around for couple of days, I found that when I change the output type of my project (in which I am using libpng.lib) to Static Lib (.lib), everything works and the code compiles well but with .dll output it throws the above specified error.

And my problem is, I have to use .dll output because that I use in another huge project which I cant change to accept .lib.

Any help on this?

Comment: The linked library isn't actually getting linked correctly. Without any information about platform and toolchain it's hard to help more. (Also possible that you have a C/C++ declaration mismatch but the linker error's symbol name isn't mangled, so I think you're OK there.)

Comment: @BenZotto: The code is written and compiled under visual studio 2008 on windows 7. OpenGL is used to render the graphics. I want these graphics to be saved as png. Let me know if you require any specific info. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question (getting libpng to link), but an alternative which is much easier to integrate (it is a single source file with no dependencies and a very liberal licence) can be found here: http://nothings.org/stb/stb_image_write.h

Comment: Please see my edit for narrowed down and updated issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing "pnglibconf.h" which you must copy from
scripts/pnglibconf.h.prebuilt to pnglibconf.h in your source directory.

Comment: I tied it but it did not work. Getting the same error: "Unresolved External Symbol".

Comment: I don't see it in your code snippet, but I assume you've got an '#include "png.h"' somewhere, right?

Comment: I have placed all the headers files properly. Please see my edit for narrowed down and updated issue. Thanks